# Horizontal moving of datalist items should stop on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, asp.net

All the items are bound to the datalist from SQL Server without any problem, but these items should scroll horizontally and should stop on mouse hover.

Here's the code:

```
<div style="Width:500px;height:200px;">
    <asp:DataList ID="ItemsDatalist" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="ItemHyperlink" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/WebForm1.aspx">
                <div>
                    <asp:Image ID="itemImage" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
<div>
```

Comment: could you elaborate on your desired result: what do you mean scroll horizontally and stop on mouse hover?!

Comment: Hi deostroll,The datalist items should automatically move from left to right in the div and each individual item should stop moving on mouse hover.Thank you